# Difference between declaration terminated incorrectly and declaration syntax error in C

Tags: c

I want to know when this difference happen Declaration terminated error and declaration syntax.

my code for Declaration terminated error:

```
int a=12,245;
```

and code for declaration syntax error:

```
int a=10 20 30;
```

Comment: Well what you are doing is not legal C and I am not sure what your intent is with these statements.  The first one looks like it could be a 5 digit number you want to put in, but C does not use commas to separate digit groupings.

Comment: Both are syntax errors. The difference is that in the former the `,` is correct but the next token must be a `(`, `*` or an identifier...

Comment: A comma `,` is an operator in C, you cannot use it to separate a number.

Comment: Dear friend, I know both are the syntax error but want the difference in between

Comment: If I say "1 + 1 = 3" it's wrong.  If I say "1 + 1 = orange" it's also wrong.  What's the difference?

Comment: Why are you asking?  Are you taking a quiz where someone's asking you to classify these errors?  Are you using a compiler that's giving you these different messages?  Are you writing a compiler, and wondering what error messages you should have it emit for different errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can say

```
int a = 12245;
```

and you're initializing `a` to the integer 12245.

You can say

```
double a = 12.245;
```

and you're initializing `a` to the floating-point decimal number 12.245.

If you want to confuse people, you might be able to say

```
int a = (12,245);
```

and this is like saying "I want to initialize `a` to 12, no, I mean 245".  (`a` would end up holding 245).

But you can't say

```
int a = 12,245;
```

The comma character can be used in several different ways in C, but there are also several ways that it can *not* be used.

In C source code, you have to use the full stop `.` as a decimal point, and you can't use a comma to group numbers into thousands or lakh or anything.

What you can use commas for are to separate the arguments in a function call, or to declare several variables at once, or as the *comma operator*.  But these are all quite different, and `int a = 12,245;` doesn't end up fitting any of them.

For completeness, here are argument-separating commas in a function call:

```
printf("%d %c %s %f\n", 1, '2', "three", 4.5);
```

Here are commas separating multiple declarations:

```
int a = 12, b = 245;
```

Here are comma operators:

```
for(i = 0, j = n; i < j; i++, j--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer can not tape floating point values like 10,3, Integer can only store natural numbers like 180! If you want to use floating point values, use **float** or **double**

Answer (score 0):

In C, there is no difference. Both programs fail to conform to the syntax of the language.

C does not specify the text of error or warning messages produced by a compiler. Most compilers make some effort to produce error messages which help the programmer understand what the error is. Some do better than others, but none is perfect.

Whatever compiler you are using, in its current version, happens to produce two different error messages for that code. How it decided which message to produce is something probably only the authors of that compiler could tell you. If you feel that one or the other error message is significantly misleading, you could file a bug report or a formal complaint, if the compiler you are using has some sort of user-support channel which allows you to do one of those things.